# How can I get clean soil for my sundew?

Tags: soil, repotting, carnivorous-plants

When I bought my [Drosera Aliciae](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Drosera_aliciae.jpg), I was told that I have to repot it in a clean soil - without any nutrients. Unfortunately, all gardening stores in my neighborhood sell only standard garden soil, that contains nutrients.

How can I get clean soil for my sundew? Can I e.g. collect sand from the seashore? Can I take garden soil and clean it somehow?

Answer (score 4):

Most of the carnivorous plants require a soil that is free from pesticides, trace elements from chlorinated water and "nutrients".  In this case nutrients refer to Nitrogen, Phosphorous and Potassium that are commonly available in most soils and are higher in soils with more organic matter like compost.

What this plant needs is a soil mix that you can make yourself that mimics the natural environment where they are found.

- one part peat moss or sphagnum moss the fluffier precursor of peat and one part [sharp or silica sand](http://www.wisegeek.org/what-is-silica-sand.htm).

This mix will draw water up from a substrate and have very few nutrients.  Once it dries out it will be hard to re wet so you can add some perlite if available.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to get proper soil for anything you are planting in pots is to use a sterilized potting soil.  Do not try to make your own soil by adding anything other than decomposed organic matter, big no no.  All soil is ONLY improved by adding decomposed organic mulch and all one has to do it apply it to the top of the soil. Even and especially potting soil.  Lots of these potting soils come with Mycorrhizae and Bacterias.  One needs to FEED these micro organisms with decomposed organic matter.  Makes the sterilized potting soil come alive with organisms.  Garden soil is like taking a chunk out of an evolved environment and NOT at all good for a 'terrarium' like a potted plant.  I am not sure what you are calling 'nutrients'...are you talking about added fertilizers?  Then you are correct, do not use potting soil with added fertilizer.